# Why isn't there an option to hide CSS in snippets?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-snippets

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736476/why-is-this-custom-volume-animation-slider-not-working-as-expected) I had some CSS included to make an example look neat, but it doesn't need to be seen - it just clutters up the question. Why isn't there an option to hide CSS and perhaps HTML too?

Note: As an afterthought, maybe some people even want to hide the JS and keep the CSS and / or HTML.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Not my vote, but voting on questions tagged [meta-tag:feature-request] is based on whether people agree or disagree with the proposed feature.

Comment: And in case you were about to ask: No, Meta votes don't add to or remove from your reputation.

Comment: @theB Oh I knew it doesnt affect rep. I just wanted to understand the reasoning for disagreeing with the feature.

Comment: @Viziionary Some opinions don't really need a reasoning, at least not worthy of a comment. It can be as simple as 'I don't think it's beneficial to the site'. It can be purely subjective, so there's nothing to comment - and a downvote expresses this just as much as a vague comment would.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree. CSS can be used to download random external things like background images or other stylesheets.

This could be used to track or infect me, and I don't want that.

Moreover, it's trivial to inject JavaScript in the CSS part of the stack snippet. And running hidden JS would be **much, much worse**. JS is turing complete so it can be used to do lots of things, including nasty ones.

Therefore, before I run a stack snippet, I want to see what code will run.